# How to extract a set of numbers on the same column from each page of a PDF?

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, tabula

I need to extract two numbers from each page (under 'Drop/Handle' column)  of a PDF that ranges from 7-9 pages. Here's a sample PDF: https://www.nj.gov/oag/ge/docs/Financials/MGR2017/201701revenue.pdf

Rather than writing individual scripts for each page, is there a code that I can use to automatically detect the two numbers based on its position? (The numbers are almost always in the same position and format for every page).

So far I've been doing this

```
files = '201701revenue.pdf'
path = r'C:\Users\201701revenue.pdf' 

df = tabula.read_pdf(path, pages = 'all', index_col=0, multiple_tables=True)
df=df[0] 
df=df[[6]]
df=df[3:6]
df=df.drop([4])
df.columns=['Casino Handle']
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df['Casino Handle'] = df['Casino Handle'].str.replace(",","").str.replace(" ","")
df['Casino Handle'] = df['Casino Handle'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df=df.append(df.sum(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)
df=df.drop([0,1])

df.append(df1, ignore_index=True)
```

Despite having tabula read all pages, it recognizes two separate tables per page so if I were to call for the specific column, an error comes up saying `KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([6], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"`

Comment: Try posting code of what you already tried, and any information you may have on why it doesn't work.

Comment: I edited my post to include the code I used. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what is your expected output for df? also, what is df1?